# Moving a relationship arrow in an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench's data modeling tool?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there any way to move a relationship arrow in an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench's data modeling tool? (without having to move or resize any table)

E.g. before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The relationships are laid out dynamically. You have only very limited control of that. The only layout adjustment you can do is to move the middle line in a 3-lines relationship:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Click on the line to make the grab handle visible and then drag that.